# Can we assume unicode symbols displayed well across all Android devices

Tags: android

Currently, I displaying a unicode symbol ▼ (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm) in Android device using `Roboto-Light.ttf`. I deploy my app along assets\fonts\Roboto-Light.ttf

It works well in my device. Can I assume it will work well under all different devices with different language settings?

Comment: What about devices without roboto font? (namely pre-ICS and highly stylised vendor-ROMs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I assume it will work well under all different devices with
>   different language settings?

As long as you use the font in your assets folder and not any native implementation, then yes.